# mysql count different fields depending on fields value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which looks like this:

```
from_user    to_user      type
    43          85          1
    32          43          2
    64          79          1
    77          43          4
    54          43          5
    13          96          4
    78          43          6
```

I have a variable `$user`, and I need a query which returns the sum of `from_user` (i.e. how many from_users are there) where it equals `$user`, but only if `type=1`. If type=4 or 5, I need the sum of `to_user` where it equals `$user`. Is it possible to do this in one query?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And what about the other types like 2, 3, or those after 6?

Comment: is type also an input variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  SUM(Type = 1 AND From_User = 'user_ID_HERE') From_User,
        SUM(Type IN (4,5) AND to_user = 'user_ID_HERE') To_User
FROM    TableName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec48c/4)